Understanding Formal Verification proofs of ECC algorithms in an Industrial setting
My question caters to the domain of Error Correction Codes (ECC) algorithms and the use of formal verification tools on them.
I work in the capacity of a formal verification engineer. I use the Forte Formal Verification tool(https://theory.stanford.edu/~barrett/pubs/SJO+05.pdf) for our purposes. At a high level it converts the entire boolean circuit into a ROBDD. We are trying to do a proof using this tool of an ECC algorithm $E$, given by the architects.
The behaviour of the ECC algorithm $E$ is as follows -

It is a variant of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code#SECDED type algorithm, and how do the designers come up with this algorithm is black box to me.
The data can be thought of as a boolean matrix, $M$ of size $8\times$max_rows.
The data is multiplied with an encoder matrix to come up with locator and parity bits to the data.
The read_data (that is data that reaches the other side of the channel) is multiplied with the decoder matrix to give us information about the parity and locator syndrome based on which they have an understanding of the granularity of the error incurred.
Thus the algorithm can detect No Error, Correctible Error (CE), Uncorrectable Error.
The correctible error flag occurs when there are 1,2,3,4 corruptions introduced to the original data. Where $i$ corruption means any $i$ rows get corrupted.

The tool allows us to play around with symbolic variables which can choose a particular row ($r$) and inject a corruption $\vec{c}$. Basically this means we are able to generate corrupted Matrix $M_c$ from $M$ where $M_c[r] = M[r] \oplus \vec{c}$.
In a certain sense, I have the following variables, $r_1, \ldots r_4, c_1, \ldots, c_4$ and ECC algorithm ${E}$  (where $r_i$ is a row variable, $c_i$ is a correction vector) with which I write down a verification function $V(r_1, \ldots r_4, c_1, \ldots , c_4)$ that works on algorithm $E$ to check the properties asserted in the specification match or not.
Given this above setting, with the formal verification tool above we are able to verify the ECC algorithm sketch the architects provide us. From what I understood, it seems at the end of the day I actually verify the encoder and decoder matrices of the ECC algorithm these architects have come up with as well as the transformation flow of data (that is being padded with locator and parity bits) and finally the locator and parity syndrome computation flow to assess the corruption correction granularity.
Given my gap in understanding of ECC algorithms and the operational details of how the architects in the electronics industry function, I wanted to know the following.
My belief is that ECC algorithms once constructed can be most likely mathematically proven to be correct and not left to intuition, like there should be a possible pen paper proof to analysing whether the algorithm meets it's requirements. But even then the architects need the help of the verification tool which proves their intuition.
What I wanted to know are :

Do large scale ECC algorithms get quickly computationally intricate enough that they need the help of the tools to figure out if the intuition matches?
How could the ECC algorithm designers have come up with the encoder decoder matrices in the first place? Their rules of play are the error/correctible states they want to tune, I believe those design choices affect what the actual encoding and decoding matrices would be. Could someone break this down further?
Finally, can we use the verification tool to do the reverse process of suggesting improvements to the architect's intuition? Like say come up with details of ECC algorithm $E'$ using the verification tool. Say come up with encoder and decoder matrices which satisfy a requirement of having 5 corruption correction possible. I understand this might be harder to handle by the tool, but theoretically we should be able to go back and forth in this process, right?

